# How does socket.io detect client disconnection

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm aware that socket.io can handle disconnection through the `'disconnect'` event.

My question is: how does the `'disconnect'` event get triggered on the server-side when the client closes the webpage ?

My opinion: when client closes the webpage, the `'onunload'` event's callback launches an `emit('disconnect')`.

Am I right ?

Thanks !

EDIT:

> From [learnBoost](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO):
>
> **sync disconnect on unload** defaults to false:
> Do we need to send a disconnect packet to server when the browser unloads.

Perhaps, it's now **true** by default... I checked in the code, still **false** by default.

Comment: It pulls on the connected lines. If there's no resistance, the line is probably disconnected. (Seriously, though: I've not a clue)

Comment: The server sends heartbeats to the clients at a set interval, if it doesn't receive the heartbeat then it disconnects.

Comment: Ben Fortune: the 'disconnect' event is triggered immediatly once I close the webpage. There is no time let for an heartbeat check.

Comment: Best way to test it would be to kill the browser process, you might find it does both a "heartbeat" check as well as triggering the onUnload event

Comment: Steven: in my context, the client closes properly the webpage. Once the page is closed, the 'disconnect' event is immediatly triggered on the server-side. There's no heartbeat request before that.